# How to prevent the spreedsheet to round the currency value upto 3 values after dot i.e 10.999

Tags: c#

I want to know how to code in Csharp so that the value of currency prevent to round up in spreedsheet upto three place after dot(.) i.e 10.999 must show in spreedsheet. Currently iam passing 10.999 value of currency  in code that create spreedsheet ,when iam selecting to download spreedsheet currency value get roundup it shows 11 in place of 10.999. 
Any suggestion to get value 10.999?

Comment: What spreadsheet. Like an Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Can you provide more information? What is this spreadsheet that you are using? Do you have any sample code that you can show us?

Comment: sb.Append("<td>");
                                        sb.Append(stmtresponce.StatementHeader[IndexSec].WalletCurrency);
                                        sb.Append("</td>");
                                        sb.Append("<td>");

Comment: Above code is used to create a .xls extension file but it round up the value of cells (stmtresponce.StatementHeader[IndexSec].WalletCurrency) i.e 10.999 to 11 how to specify .xls file not to round value display as iam passing on the code.

Comment: Looks like excel column is set to General Format instead of a number with two decimal places.  See what happens if you manually change format of excel to a number.  If this works then you can make change in c# code.

Comment: yes able to display two digits after dot(.) . like 7.99 but when value comes  10.999 it shows it 11. So is it possible code that display 10.999 excel sheet not 11. I have tried to convert decimal value to string still excel assume it decimal and perform rounding.